# What kind of certificate (signed by public authority) is needed for mTLS?

Tags: nginx, ssl, mtls

I have nginx setup with mTLS with manually created CA certificate in virtual host. For SSL we use Let's encrypt.

```
ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/ca.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
```

I am able to connect to this server via curl with `--cert && --key`  parameters. Everything works.

Problem is because we should use (audit!) cert which is signed by verified authority. What kind of certificate do we need in order to get started? There are so many options on e.g. godaddy/comodo .. Chat GPT is mentioning `client certificate` but I can't find anything useful online. I am setting up staging environment - I am looking for cheap solution (not super secure option).

I tried to create "client certificate" via let's encrypt (I created another NS record and then downloaded private/public key). I was hoping that I will be able to use public key via `ssl_client_certificate` option. It didn't work.

In order to run mTLS, I will need Let's encrypt for SSL + additional certificate for mTLS, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options depend on what clients you want to authenticate with the client certificate:

- If this is about having additional protection for your site with a single user (i.e. yourself) just use a self-signed certificate which you configure as trusted in nginx
- If you want to distinguish between different employees in your own company, third party service providers or similar you can run your own company CA to issue and manage these certificates.
- If you want to accept external users where the identity is somehow verified by a trusted party you should setup this trusted party as the accepted certificate authority in nginx and ask the users to identify themselves to this CA to get their certificate